# DLookUp to match data with previous month's data

Tags: microsoft-access

The long story here is that I have Inception to date data, and I'd like to extract month to date data from it using this logic: `ITD_Current - ITD_Previous = MTD_Current`. I'm thinking that some sort of `DLookUp` could help with this.

The way the data is structured is like this:

```
Company Code | Store Number (multiple store # to a company code) | Date (yyyymm) | ITD Data
```

My first experiment was to make a unique key for each row using

```
 [Company Code] & [Store Number] & [Date]
```

which I called Key_Current. I then made a `Key_Previous` column which would be the exact format as above, but with the date value set back by one month. I then went to create a DLookUp function something like this:

```
DLookUp("[ITD Data]","Table",[Key_Current]=[Key_Prev])
```

This is clearly not working, but hopefully someone can understand what I'm trying to get at. What I need is to pull in the previous inception to date column, and match it with the current inception to date column. I can then expand the formula to subtract current from previous.

Any thoughts on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition must be passed as string.

```
DLookUp("[ITD Data]", "Table", "[Key_Current]=[Key_Prev]")
```

However, the current key will never be like the previous key, so this never yields any result.

A simple `DLookUp` will not work, since it operates only on a single row. Assuming that you know the key of the current data, you can do this

```
Dim currentKey As String, prevKey As String

currentKey = <somehow get this key>
prevKey = DLookUp("[Key_Prev]", "Table", "[Key_Current]='" & currentKey &"'")
prevData = DLookUp("[ITD Data]", "Table", "[Key_Current]='" & prevKey &"'")
```

Probably a better way to do it is to make a query

```
SELECT A.*, A.[ITD Data] - Nz(B.[ITD Data]) As MTG_Current
FROM
    Table A
    LEFT JOIN Table B
        ON A.[Key_Prev] = B.[Key_Current]
```

You can join the table to itself to compare different rows.

Comment: The best way to accomplish this was definitely the query. What an elegant solution! Thank you.